# Substitution for Suet in Christmas Pudding

Tags: substitutions, beef, fat

I'm interested in making a traditional Christmas pudding but I've never seen suet available in the stores around here. Assuming I can't find any, what would be a good substitution?

Comment: Step 1: acquire a piglet. (seriously, what's your geography?)

Comment: Any butcher should have suet, they won't have it on display (not these health conscious days). I'd be surprised if they can't produce some on request. I use it once or twice a year (a very small peice in with roast veg gives them an incredible flavour), and my butcher never charges me for it.

Comment: @Binary You will find it's quite country dependant. In some countries it's just not possible to obtain suet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Christmas pudding, there really is no substitute. In some recipes it's possible to use finely grated, very hard, unsalted butter, or a vegetable shortening, but the results are just not the same.

Answer (score 1):

Use beef fat or lard if your butcher can't supply.